# How to iterate over an iterator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator

As stated [here](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_generators.html#_iteratorprototype) all ES6 iterators are iterable (as a consequence, you can apply for-of etc. to them).
Considering the following short demonstration, I'm trying to figure out why I cannot iterate over `it` and I get *TypeError: it is not iterable* error.

```
var counter ={
   [Symbol.iterator](){
      var start=0, end=10, step=1;
      var current = start; 

      return {
        next(){
          var done = current > end;
          if(done) return {value: undefined, done: true};        
          var res = {value: current, done: false};
          current += step;
          return res;
      }
    }
  }
}
  

var it = counter[Symbol.iterator]();

for(let t of it){
  console.log(t)
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: either `for(let t of counter) ...` or you add `return { [Symbol.iterator](){ return this }, next(){...}}`.

Comment: I want to know how iterators are iterable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement doesn't say "*all iterators are iterable*", but "*all iterators that are built into ES6 do inherit from `IteratorPrototype` and are thereby iterable*". Your custom iterator `{next(){…}}` is a plain object and not iterable because it doesn't have (or inherit) a `Symbol.iterator` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
let counter = {
  from: 1,
  to: 5,

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    this.current = this.from;
    return this;
  },

  next() {
    if (this.current <= this.to) {
      return { done: false, value: this.current++ };
    } else {
      return { done: true };
    }
  }
};

let it = counter[Symbol.iterator]();

for(let t of it){
  console.log(t)
}
```

Your Iterable implementation on any object should be like above, such that it should always be returning the object with a Symbol. But, in case you're returning an object with a next() function. Just check what your "it" holds inside it, you would have your answer.

Ideally, **counter** and **it** variables should have objects like below,

```
counter;
{from: 1, to: 5, next: ƒ, current: 6, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ}
it;
{from: 1, to: 5, next: ƒ, current: 6, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ}
```

Reference: https://javascript.info/iterable

Answer (score -1):

```
const counter = {
 from: 1,
 to: 10
}

counter[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
 return {
   current: this.from,
   last: this.to,
   next() {
    if (this.current <= this.last) {
     return { done: false, value: this.current++ };
    } else {
     return { done: true }
    }
   }
 }
}


for(let num of counter) {
 console.log(num)
}
```